# CSS overlay effect is disturbing CSS text on image

Tags: html, css

I need to display a text on the image using CSS. I'm doing that using H2 tag:

```
<h2 class="post-message">Test</h2>
```

Here is the code for CSS:

```
 .post-message {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  font: 14px Sans-Serif;
}
```

But the overlay effect is messing things up and here is the code:

```
.overlay{
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #000;
}

.overlay img{
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform .3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform .3s ease-out;
    transition: transform .3s ease-out;
}

.overlay:hover img{ 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(-5deg);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(-5deg);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(-5deg);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(-5deg);
    transform: scale(1.2) rotate(-5deg);
    opacity: 0.7;   
}
```

I don't know how to explain what happens and I uploaded 2 screens:

1. This screen shows the original image without Mouse hover: https://s22.postimg.org/xrsohlcw1/without_mouse_over.jpg
   On the first image you see a gray background that I don't know from where comes
2. The second image is the mouse over effect: that gray image is rotating according to overlay effect and is displayed at the right corner only :/ 
   https://s22.postimg.org/a13x0ndmp/gra_color_disappears.jpg

A little red arrow will show you what happens on the second image. A help would be great! I tried all possible things that I knew, expert opinion always is the best solution. Thanks in advance!

```
<div class="post-thumbnail overlay">
    <a href="http://example.com/comey-wikileaks/">      
        <img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/comey-825x510.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image"  width="825" height="510">       
    </a>    
    <h2 class="post-message">Test</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the relevant HTML?

Comment: I added the wordpress code above.

Comment: Please post the actual outputed markup, not the PHP. Your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Added :) thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `img` has a "replaced content" layout model and basically treated as an inline element, and that includes space at the bottom by default for the bottom part of characters, so there will be a small space between the bottom of an `img` and the bottom of the `img`'s container. To remove that gap at the bottom, either make the `img` `display: block` or use `vertical-align: top`.

If the image is rotating so far that you see the corner of it in the bottom/right corner, either increase your `scale()` or don't rotate as much until you can't see that anymore. I don't see it with the code you provided.

```css
 .post-message {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 10px;
   left: 10px;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
   padding: 4px 8px;
   color: white;
   margin: 0;
   font: 14px Sans-Serif;
 }
 
 .overlay {
   overflow: hidden;
   background: #000;
 }
 
 .overlay img {
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: -moz-transform .3s ease-out;
   -o-transition: -o-transform .3s ease-out;
   transition: transform .3s ease-out;
 }
 
 .overlay:hover img {
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(-5deg);
   -moz-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(-5deg);
   -o-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(-5deg);
   -ms-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(-5deg);
   transform: scale(1.2) rotate(-5deg);
   opacity: 0.7;
 }
 
 img {
   vertical-align: top;
 }
```

```html
<div class="post-thumbnail overlay">
  <a href="http://example.com/comey-wikileaks/">
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" width="825" height="510">
  </a>
  <h2 class="post-message">Test</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Great explanation. I already tried display: block now I will try the second option you suggested. Ups, I have had problems with position: absolute it was moving to the bottom the h2 element so I had to use position: relative, maybe because of this, you didn't see the same? Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

You could actually put your `img` together with your `<h2>` inside a `<div>` and let the whole `<div>` rotate....

Here is an example base on what you wrote:

(obvously, there's a few things to readjust, but it's more or less what you want, I guess ^^)

```css
.post-message {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  font: 14px Sans-Serif;
}

.overlay{
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #000;
    
    /*these two lines are new*/
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}

/*I apply style directly on the "overlay"*/
.overlay /*img*/{
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:    -moz-transform .3s ease-out;
      -o-transition:      -o-transform .3s ease-out;
         transition:         transform .3s ease-out;
}

.overlay:hover /*img*/{ 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(-5deg);
       -moz-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(-5deg);
         -o-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(-5deg);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(-5deg);
            transform: scale(1.2) rotate(-5deg);
            
    opacity: 0.7;   
}
```

```html
<span class="overlay">
  <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" />
  <h2 class="post-message">Test</h2>
</span>
```

Comment: this solution also works like a charm! I just realized what was my mistake. Thanks Johannes!